# Reload part of the page depending on the values of combo box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[image]
I want to reload the table part using the values given in the box. When i will press view, it will show the desired table taking the values from the combo box and combo box will have the show the value that i have given.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>

<tr>
    <th>Order Number</th>
    <th>Order Date</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>ProductLine</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Customer Name</th>
 <th>Employee Name</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <?php
  include('./process/connection.php');
  while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$res['orderNumber']."</td>" ;
  echo "<td>".$res['orderDate']."</td>" ;enter code here
  echo "<td>".$res['status']."</td>" ;
  echo "<td>".$res['productName']."</td>" ;
  echo "<td>".$res['productLine']."</td>" ;
  echo "<td>".$res['amount']."</td>" ;
  echo "<td>".$res['customerName']."</td>" ;
  echo "<td>".$res['Employee']."</td>" ;
  echo "<tr>";

  }
  ?>
 </table>
```

Comment: We need more info to help you. How are the `HTML` code? Are you using jQuery datatables?

Comment: Use jQuery **[Data tables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)**

Comment: If you show the HTML we might be able to give you more help.

Comment: No i am not using any jquery datatable.

Comment: And what did you tried so far?

Comment: on click event of show button use ajax to get the content in html format which your existing table uses then replace the <tbody> of your table with new html returned via ajax

Comment: I tried using jquery and ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can try jQuery Form plugin (a.k.a ajaxForm) http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#myForm').ajaxForm('target': '#divToUpdate');
 });
```

In HTML you should make standard form (GET or POST), action page should return only page fragment which will be loaded into #divToUpdate